# Node.js Socket.io Ionic Nginx - wrong configuration?

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, ionic-framework

I`m new with sockets and nginx, what I am trying to do is use the sockets to make a post of order.

With the configuration that I currently have, the API works fine (I get and send data without problems), but when I send the order (the route that uses the sockets), it seems that the server does not receive the json.

```
Using: 
 - Server CentOS 7.
 - nginx version: nginx/1.16.1
 - MongoDB 4.2
 - Node 12.13.1
```

Running localy it works without problems, because i don't use Nginx.

On **/etc/nginx/conf.d/my-domain.conf** i have this:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     xx.xx.xx.xxx;

        location /socket.io/ {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;

                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                proxy_pass "http://localhost:8080/socket.io/";
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass "http://localhost:8080/";
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
                location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                location = /50x.html {
        }
}
```

**============================   Server-side:  ===========================**

**server.js**

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('linstening on port:', port);
});
```

**sockets.js**

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {    
    socket.on('post-order', function (order) {

        orderDAO.post(order, function (err, ord) {
            if(err) return console.log('Error:', err);
            io.emit('post-order', ord);
        }

    });
});
```

**order.js**

```
app.post('/api/v1/orders', function (req, res) {

    let order= req.body;

    orderDAO.post(order, function (err, ord) {
        if (err) {
            res.send({'err': err});
        } else {
            res.json(ord);
        }
    });
});
```

**orderDAO.js**

```
function OrdersDAO(db) {

    let ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    let database = db.db('app_habb');
    let orders= database.collection('orders')

    this.post = function (order, callback) {

        orders.insertOne(order, function (err, result) {
            if (err) return callback(err, null);
            return callback(null, result.ops[0]);
        });

    }
}
```

**============================   Client-side:  ===========================**

**generate-order.ts**

```
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';

constructor(private socket: Socket) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.connect();

    this.socket.on('post-order', (data) => {  // receives nothing
        console.log(data);
    });
}

sendOrder() {
    // Validation code..
    // ...

    // then:
    this.socket.emit("post-order", this.order);
}
```

Is what I am trying possible? I mean I'm sending a json through socket.

If that is possible, what is going wrong?

I do not receive any error when I make the request.